NodeJs Application memory usage is increasing
I created Application with multitenant structure using nodejs, expressjs and mongoose when I start the application the memory usage for its process it normal but with time few hours and usage few users the memory is increasing so much reach for 2-3GBps even number of users is not that much 5 users.
Methodology
I created the multitenant architecture by starting the connection to the database using mongoose without specifying the database and utilizing mongoose object after that, And  checking the tenant in each request then use the respective model if its created, If not ! to create it and use it,

Request with Token >> Validate the token user and check the Tenant >> Use | Create Model >> Query the database >> Send back the response

Mongoose Model Class
export class Category {
  private db = "";
  private model = "Category";
  private collection = "categories";
  constructor(db: string, model?: string, collection?: string) {
    this.db = db;
    this.model = model || this.model;
    this.collection = collection || this.collection;
  }

  schema = new Schema<ICategoryBaseDocument>(
    {
      // model schema 
    },
    { 
      // model options
     }
  );

    Model = (): ICategoryModel => { // method to get or create model
    const db = mongoose.connection.useDb(dbConnection(this.db).name); // this function will return the name of the database for that specific tenant 
    if (db.modelNames().indexOf(this.model) !== -1) {
      return db.models[this.model] as ICategoryModel;
    } else {
      return db.model<ICategoryBaseDocument, ICategoryModel>(
        this.model,
        this.schema,
        this.collection
      );
    }
  };
}

Database Connection
Database is general mongoose connection start with the application start with no database referred and uses that connection to swap between databases from the models have been created
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${server}:${port}`, {});

I feel that approach is not the best practice and its the reason behind memory usage so please any recommendation or idea how to fix it

What version of Mongoose are you using? If you're not using 8.8.2 or later the memory usage could be due to the issue fixed in https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/15039.

I am using  "mongoose": "^8.8.0", should I update it ?

The caret constraint should match >=8.8.0 <9.0.0. You can check your package-lock.json to see which version is installed, and update as needed.
